# Option key does not work as Meta in Tmux

Tags: macos, osx-lion, tmux

I am using Mac OSX Lion. I have checked "Use Option key as Meta" in Terminal preferences. Although the Option key seems to work fine as Meta in Bash, when I use it in Tmux (over SSH) it does not work properly. I am trying to use TMUX shortcuts like `^b M-1` `b M-2` etc. I can get these with the ESC key but not the Option key.

Comment: `^b Space` with cycle through the various layouts

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I would suggest using [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/) instead of the default Terminal.app, as it is better for many reasons.

Specifically, you would be interested in iTerm2's options to map left/right option as "+Esc", which works much better than trying to have it emulate Meta for every purpose I can think of or have tried.

This setting is located under:

- Preferences

  - Profiles

    - [select a profile]

      - Keys

Comment: I was looking for a reason to move to iTerm2 and here I have it. Thanks!!

Comment: May I ask why you choose to set option to "+Esc" and not to "Meta" when it sounds like you're trying to use Meta-keys? What is the difference / why is "+Esc" better? Thanks!

Comment: When you hover over the "Meta" and "+Esc" options in iTerm2, there's a tooltip that says "+Esc is the preferred setting for users who don't need the option key to enter diacritics or other special character."

Answer (score 39):

For other folks who find their way here via their favorite search engine, I was able to solve this problem by simply going to Preferences -> Profiles -> Keyboard and checking "Use Option as Meta key" for the terminal profile I'm using.

I'm running `weechat` under `tmux`, and default key bindings make heavy use of the `meta` key.

Comment: you save my day!

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a way to solve this without having to switch to iTerm2.

Comment: The issue with that approach is, you can't use a bunch of characters anymore on some keyboard layouts, like tilde, some brackets and backward slash for example ][{}\

Comment: Tip: You can do the same in iterm2 and also use `ESC+`

Answer (score 7):

I'm also sticking to `Terminal.app`, and since no other answer solved the issue I'm adding my own that worked for me.

Besides configuring the current Profile in `Terminal -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Select the profile to configure -> Keyboard` and checking `Use Option as Meta key`, also look through the default list of bindings in the table just above and make sure that the combinations you want to assign are free. For me there were a few `Option + Arrow` keys that were interfering with `tmux` configuration to easily change between panes.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and none of the answers provided here worked. That is, I too had the **iTerm2** `[Option]` key remapped to `[+Esc]` (aka. "fallback"-`[META]`) in my "Preferences -> Profiles -> Keyboard", as described in the other answers, but still could not change my tmux pane layout with `[CTRL]-[b]`, `[+Esc/META]-[DIGIT]`.

Then I found that under "Preferences -> Keys", there is a "Navigation Shortcuts" where `[Option]` + (any) `[DIGIT]` is mapped to "switch split panes" (remember `[Option]` is remapped to `[+Esc]`, so that's a clear collision). Therefore, after un-setting that (to an empty key value), I finally can again comfortably resize my tmux panes with `[CTRL]-[b]`, `[+Esc/META]-[DIGIT]` (instead of having to use `[CTRL]-[b]`, (the real) `[Esc]`, and then the desired layout `[DIGIT]`).

Answer (score 2):

In my `.zshrc` I usually have the following set:

```
bindkey '^[[1;9C' forward-word
bindkey '^[[1;9D' backward-word
```

Within tmux sessions, I had to additionally include

```
bindkey '^[[1;3C' forward-word
bindkey '^[[1;3D' backward-word
```

You can figure out these codes by running `read` in a session, then pressing the keyboard shortcuts, e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>.

My keys are set as follows in iTerm2:

[image]